# Falcon Boom Poles - Any Thoughts?

Tags: boom-pole, gear, location-recording, purchase-advice, booming

I was looking around Ebay, to find a good deal on a boom pole, since I lost mine on a shoot and I came across this listing.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/9-ft-Carbon-Fiber-Microphone-BOOM-POLE-The-Lux-Falcon-Boompole-for-mics-/221173884469?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item337efda635

I wanted to know if anyone on here has ever used these and if they're worth investing in or if I should just save up and get a K-Tek instead.

Comment: I'd love to hear some kind of review too. And I can't find the 12 ft version on ebay... 9ft seems a bit short for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find this thread [here](http://www.dv-forums.com/forums/showthread.php?t=7159)  :)

Answer (score 1):

Interressting. Seems to be somehow affordeble. Are there some testers of this anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dv-forums.com/forums/showthread.php?t=7159